# cross-classified multilevel logistic model?

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I am helping a colleague with some multi-level analyses and am getting stuck on how to set the model up and could use some advice.  Students were classified as belonging to either "TD" or "SL" group ("Group").  They then completed 4 different conditions where they had to remember and repeat back words from a list or lists ("Condition"). The conditions had 1,2,3, or 4 lists of 4 words each (so in condition 4, they were presented with 4 lists of 4 words). They then recorded how many were correctly remembered in each condition. All participants completed all 4 conditions.

Words for each list were randomly selected from a pool of 20 words, so some words appear more than once across the 4 conditions for a particular participant. Each participant had a different set of words for the four conditions (so ID1 may have had the word "book" in condition 1, but ID2 may have had that word in Condition 4). Each word has a density value ("Density").
For each word, they have whether the student remember it correctly (dichotomous yes/no).

They are interested in the interaction of Group, Condition, and Density.

I believe this should be a cross-classified logistic multi-level model.  I am thinking of it as a 3-level model, with Student at level 3, Condition at Level 2, and Word at level 3.  Group would be a level-3 predictor, and Density would be a level-1 predictor.  The model would have random effects for Participant and Word.

Am I totally off-base here? How would you set this up?

Can I estimate this model in HLM?